# Render polygon with repeate Texture in Libgdx using PolygonSpriteBatch

Tags: opengl, textures, libgdx

I would like to draw a polygon with repeat texture (e.g brick). Here is my code:

```
textureBrick = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/brick.png"));
textureBrick.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);


TextureRegion texreg = new TextureRegion(textureBrick,0,0,1f,1f);
texreg.setTexture(textureBrick);
PolygonRegion po = new PolygonRegion(texreg, floatvertices);
```

and next i draw (render):

```
public void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, PolygonSpriteBatch polygonBatch) {
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    polygonBatch.draw(po, 0,0, 512f, 256f);
}
```

Unfortunately, I always gets polygons filled by white colour. Why?

Comment: your code seems fine... please provide more code to figure out the problem. also provide the LIBGDX version that you are using as from current nighties 0.9.9 this code won't be valid as polygon region takes triangles as well in nightlies. I am assuming that you would have used only Polygon sprite batch and rendering is done between polygonbatch.begin() and polygonbatch.end()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be calling code in this order

```
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 0, 0, 480, 480);
polygonBatch.begin();
polygonBatch.draw(polygonRegion, 0,0, 400f, 400f);  
polygonBatch.end();
spriteBatch.end();
```

Using spriteBatch,polygonBatch, shapeRenders etc together might lead to this type of problem you should use them seperately :

```
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 0, 0, 480, 480);
spriteBatch.end();
polygonBatch.begin();
polygonBatch.draw(polygonRegion, 0,0, 400f, 400f);  
polygonBatch.end();
```

Before using begin of any other batch you should end the previous batch.

Comment: after use spriteBatch and polygonBatch separately drawing polygon works

Comment: Can I use only polygon batch to do all the drawing?, or is there any benefit to use spriteBatch and polygonBatch separately?