# Box2D Body with Texture?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I know how to apply sprite to a Box2d body, but is there a way to apply a texture to it? Basically what I am trying to do is to have one texture, let's say 32x32, and then just repeat it all over the body, like the ground in this image:

[image]

Is this possible in LibGDX?

EDIT:

My latest try:

```java
Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        Vector2 mTmp = new Vector2();
        PolygonShape shape = (PolygonShape) fixture.getShape();
        int vertexCount = shape.getVertexCount();
        float[] vertices = new float[vertexCount * 2];
        for (int k = 0; k < vertexCount; k++) {
            shape.getVertex(k, mTmp);
            mTmp.rotate(body.getAngle()* MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
            mTmp.add(body.getPosition()); 
            vertices[k * 2] = mTmp.x * PIXELS_PER_METER;
            vertices[k * 2 + 1] = mTmp.y * PIXELS_PER_METER;
        }
        short triangles[] = new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(vertices).toArray();

        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/block.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
        
        PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices, triangles);
        
        poly = new PolygonSprite(region);
```

and in rendering:

```
polyBatch.begin();
        poly.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();
```

but it doesn't draw anything.

After importing different shape of level, I get this result:

[image]

Only one polygon ( shown inside of red circle ) gets the texture. Whole level is imported as a JSON file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes This is very much possible in libgdx.

You just need to create a polygon region for that

```
PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices, triangles);
```

Here textureRegion is the region that you want to repeat. 
vertices and triangles define the shape of the region.

This polygon region is a repeated texture that is form red from the vertices and triangles. You can render this region using polygon batch just same as we do it with sprite batch.

**UPDATE**

```java
PolygonShape shape = (PolygonShape) fixture.getShape();
int vertexCount = shape.getVertexCount();
float[] vertices = new float[vertexCount * 2];
for (int k = 0; k < vertexCount; k++) {
    shape.getVertex(k, mTmp);
    mTmp.rotate(body.getAngle()* MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
    mTmp.add(bodyPos); 
    vertices[k * 2] = mTmp.x * PIXELS_PER_METER;
    vertices[k * 2 + 1] = mTmp.y * PIXELS_PER_METER;
}
short triangles[] = new EarClippingTriangulator()
        .computeTriangles(vertices)
        .toArray();
PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(
        textureRegion, vertices, triangles);
```

Comment: but how do I convert my box2d ground polygon into vertices and triangles?

Comment: @RohitMalish http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html

Comment: could you explain mTmp and EAR_CLIPPING_TRIANGULATOR?

Comment: @RohitMalish as per docs 'A simple implementation of the ear cutting algorithm to triangulate simple polygons without holes'. It is a utility class that try to calculate minimum no of triangles from vertices. and mtmp is a vector2 here which we pass to box2d. it will add vertex information to this variable. If you have user PIXELS_PER_METER (any constant for camera and world mapping) then the multiplication takes care of that.

Comment: so basically we create new vector mTmp and pass it to box2d? and how about EAR_CLIPPING_TRIANGULATOR?

Comment: @RohitMalish sorry for confusion, EAR_CLIPPING_TRIANGULATOR = new EarClippingTriangulator(); I have updated my Answer also.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't draw anything. I updated my question with my latest code I tried, can you have a look at it and tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: @RohitMalish Please check that this is not the case in you code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022603/render-polygon-with-repeate-texture-in-libgdx-using-polygonspritebatch/19066628#19066628 and What value did you use for Pixel per meter?

Comment: I checked it is not that case, I end sprite batch before beginning polygonBatch. And I tried pixel per meter with values from 8 to 1000, still same result :S

Comment: Try using **texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat,TextureWrap.Repeat);** and also try logging values of texture.getWidth() and texture.getHeight() they might be zero.

Comment: wrap didnt do it either, and logging out texture size confirms that texture is not empty, it is 32x32

Comment: @RohitMalish the code you implemented seems fine. Lets try debugging the vertices and vertex count for your case. can you just check the length of triangles, vertex count for your case and the position of the polysprite. also check if it lies into current viewport or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42061/discussion-between-rohit-malish-and-vikalp-jain)